# Kio estas la diferenco inter "oferi" kaj "oferti"?

Tags: word-meaning

Mi volas diri ke mi oferas/ofertas iun servon aŭ varon. Kiun verbon mi uzu? Kaj en kia kunteksto oni uzu la alian vorton?

Ekzemple:
"Mi oferas/ofertas tranokteblecon post la zamenhofa festo."

Comment: Estas ankaŭ tria verbo en tiu konfuza mikso: _proponi_. Mi fakte ja emus uzi ĝuste tiun en via ekzemplo se ne temas pri pagenda tranokto: "mi proponas al vi tranokteblecon ĉe mi"

Comment: Do, mi ne pensis pri pagenda servo, sed eble pri frazo en pli/malpli publika invitilo. Mi jam scias, ke mi ne havas litojn por ĉiuj partoprenantoj. Mi nur "proponus" tranokteblecon al ĉiuj partoprenantoj, se fakte estus tiom da liberaj litoj en mia loĝejo. Kun "propono" mi implike jam konsentis kaj eĉ preferas tiun.
(http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/propon.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#oferi) diras pri *oferi*:

> Fordoni ion valoran por la servo, utilo de io aŭ iu

kun la ekzemplo, kio estas ege taŭga por via kunteksto:

> la urbo Bulonjo bonvole oferis gastamon (gastigon) al nia kongreso

Alia signifo estas:

> Fordoni ion valoran, por akiri alion, kion oni rigardas kiel pli valoran

[Pri *oferti*:](http://vortaro.net/#oferti)

> Proponi (varon aŭ servon) al kliento

Mia simpla solvo estas - uzi oferti se vi vendas ion (kaj se vi volas monon por tio), uzu oferi se vi volas fari ion senkoste aux estas natura interŝanĝo.

Answer (score 6):

En la *Universala Vortaro*, la difino de *oferi* estas:

> sacrifier | offer | opfern | жертвовать | ofiarować

*Ofero* estas laŭdeva fordono de karaĵo (en la Biblio, oni legas *Abraham prenis la virŝafon kaj oferis ĝin*); *oferto* estas komerca propono. Aliaj uzoj estas figurasencaj.

Por via ekzemplo, apud *proponi* konsideru *disponigi* aŭ *havebligi*:

> *Mi disponigos tranoktan ĉambron post la festo.*
>
> *Mi havebligos tranoktejon post la festo.*
>
> *Tranoktejo estos havebla ĉe mi post la Zamenhofa festo.*